# Osgi:list command not found

Tags: osgi, apache-servicemix

I have installed apache service mix 6.0 on mac.
I am starting the karat(4.0)  container using

./bin/karaf or ./bin/servicemix.

When i run the command osgi:list
I get "command not found"

but if run list i can the list of deployed components.

can somebody tell me what has changed, why is osgi:list not working

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's a Karaf 3.0.4 not 4.0.0 that is used in ServiceMix 6. 
The list of changes for the commands can be found in the [Karaf Documentation](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-3.0.x/update-notes.html)

But the osgi:* mostly changed to bundle:* as command scope.